# How to load filters in Adblock Plus when using Watir / chromedriver?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, adblock

I have a ruby script that launches a chrome browser and loads the AdBlock Plus extension.  Unfortunately I can't figure out how to load a custom filter that I've added through the options panel for the extension (I added a filter to block particular div id's).  When I load the extension it treats like it's the first time it's been loaded, so I'm wondering how to reload the state I left it in after creating the custom filter.

Here's a snippet of how I'm launching it:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = '/opt/google/chrome/chrome'
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, :switches => %w[--load extension=/home/someuser/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/1.12.1_0 --no-first-run])
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my problem.  Adding the user-data-dir switch, it now loads any settings made to the extension.

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, :switches => %w[--user-data-dir=/home/someuser/.config/google-chrome --load-extension=/home/someuser/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/1.12.1_0 --no-first-run])
```